# Why is Isabella Hartley not turned to stone instantly when she touches the obelisk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Agents of SHIELD season 2, both HYDRA and SHIELD are after the original 0-8-4 known as the obelisk/diviner.

Throughout the season, we see that anyone who comes in contact of this Kree device turn to stone instantly.

However, when [Isabella Hartley](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Isabelle_Hartley) touches the obelisk, she doesn't instantly turn to stone. Instead, her hand and arm slowly turn to stone. Later Hunter saves her by cutting her arm off.

So, my question is, why did Isabella Hartley not turn to stone instantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Throughout the season, we see that anyone who comes in contact of this Kree device turn to stone instantly.

### Not true

The Diviner seem to affect individuals differently.

For instance, the waitress who inadvertently touches the Diviner when it's inside Creel takes some time before turning to stone

Certainly, she feels something immediately and we see her feeling ill but it takes nearly a minute for the transformation to complete.

Comment: Okay. But once it started, it engulfs the entire body within seconds right? Hartley is the only exception. Why would that be?

Comment: Not seconds as I said before and obviously the answer is for "plot-reasons".